# Python ttk.Entryのstyleでreliefを指定することはできませんか？

Tags: python, tkinter

Pythonでttk.EntryでEntry ウィジットを作成しました。styleでrelief＝'SUNKEN'を指定しましたが、flat状態となります。
tk.Entryでウィジットを作成すると、ウィジット作成時のオプションでrelief＝'SUNKEN'とすれば、sunken状態にできます。
ttk.EntryではStyleがあまり機能しないのでしょうか？
ちなみにttk.Entryではfont指定についても、style指定はできず、直接ウィジット作成時のfont指定をしなければなりません。

解決手段をご存知の方がいれば、ご教示願います。

[image: 実行ダイアログ]

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Test_Dialog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dialog_size = 300, 80

        w, h = self.dialog_size

        self.dialog = ttk.tkinter.Tk()

        self.dialog.minsize(w, h)

        self._create_style_()
        self._create_widget_(self.dialog,self.dialog_size)

        self.dialog.mainloop()

    def _create_style_(self):

        self._Sytle_ = ttk.Style()

        self._Sytle_.configure(
            'MainFrame.TFrame',
            background='gainsboro',
            )

        self._Sytle_.configure(
            'WorkArea.TEntry',
            background='red',
            foreground='darkgreen',
            relief='sunken',
            )

        return

    def _create_widget_(self,dialog,size):

        dlg_w,dlg_h = size

        pad_sp = 10

        _main_frame_ = ttk.Frame(
            dialog,
            style='MainFrame.TFrame',
        )

        _work_label_ = tk.Label(
            _main_frame_,
            text = 'こちらがttk'
        )

        _work_label_2 = tk.Label(
            _main_frame_,
            text = 'こちらがtk'
        )

        _work_entry_ = ttk.Entry(
            _main_frame_,
            style='WorkArea.TEntry',
        )

        _work_entry_2 = tk.Entry(
            _main_frame_,
            #style='WorkArea.TEntry',
            relief='sunken',
        )

        _main_frame_.grid(padx=pad_sp,pady=pad_sp)
        _work_label_.grid(row=0,column=0,)
        _work_label_2.grid(row=0,column=1,)
        _work_entry_.grid(row=1,column=0,)
        _work_entry_2.grid(row=1,column=1,)

        _main_frame_.rowconfigure(0,minsize=dlg_h/2)
        _main_frame_.rowconfigure(1,minsize=dlg_h/2)
        _main_frame_.columnconfigure(0,minsize=dlg_w/2)
        _main_frame_.columnconfigure(1,minsize=dlg_w/2)

        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test_Dialog()
```

Comment: ttkは個々の要素よりはテーマが優先されるらしいです。こちらの記事を読み解くと何か出来そうです。[How to get FLAT relief Entry widget in python ttk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44383730/9014308)

Comment: `self._Sytle_ = ttk.Style()` の直後に`self._Sytle_.theme_use('classic')` を入れて、一旦スタイル・テーマを確定してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 余計なことですが、`self._Sytle_` となっていて `y` と `t` が逆になっているのは打ち間違いでしょうか？ また、`Entry` widget ではテキストエリアの背景色は `background` ではなく `fieldbackground` になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。記事を読み解いてみます。うち間違っていますね・・・。 fieldbackgroundオプションですね。試してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでご紹介いただいたページを参考に試行したところ、relief＝'SUNKEN'のスタイルと同様な見た目を適用するには非常に簡単でした。

以下の追加を行うだけで、Windowsのクラシックスタイルと同じようになります。
ただし、他のウィジットも影響を受けますので、確かめる必要があります。

```
self._Style_.theme_use('classic')
```

flatなどほかのrelief状態を作ろうとすると苦労しそうです。